Is it possible to backup data only from one table and data from other tables so it satisfies foreign key constraints from first table?
Let me give an example. There are two tables:

Tbl1 which has columns a(primary key), b, c(foreign key to Tbl2 primary key(column x))
Tbl2 which has columns x(primary key), y.

Is it possible to do backup all data of Tbl1 and also include only the necessary data from Tbl2 so it satisfies the Foreign key constraint, and not a full backup of data for Tbl2.
Tbl1



a
b
c




1
x11111
2


2
x22222
3


3
x33333
4



Tbl2



x
y




1
k11111


2
k22222


3
k33333


4
k44444


5
k55555



What I want to be included in the backup is the following:
Tbl1



a
b
c




1
x11111
2


2
x22222
3


3
x33333
4



Tbl2



x
y




1
k11111


2
k22222


3
k33333


4
k44444


5
k55555



From Tbl2 the following rows are not included:
| 1| k11111 | => NOT INCLUDED!
| 5 | k55555 | => NOT INCLUDED!

Hi Nikola and welcome to our DBA forum. it is very possible to write such a query however, Provide complete sample, see  Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

By backup, do you mean the database backup, or just "copy data somewhere else in the same database"?

@Yano_of_Queenscastle database backup. I need to move data from one database to another database on different instance, but since the data is huge I want to move only a subset of the data.

@MarcelloMiorelli added example and expected result set.


Is it possible to do backup all data of Tbl1

No. Backups are for the whole DB only. Sadly, you can't backup just selected few tables.
I guess you might be able to copy data elsewhere and then perform the backup, but there is no nice out-of-the-box solution.
